# How to welcome somebody formally and friendly / informally?

Tags: register

Let's suppose you're going to welcome somebody; which one of the following sentences sound more natural in AE and what is the natural ones difference from the formality point of view?

> - It is a pleasure to have you here
> - I am pleased to have you here.
> - It’s nice to have you here.
> - I’m glad to have you here.
> - It’s so good to have you here.

Comment: There is very little difference between these: it is merely a matter of opinion which is preferable in a a particular situation.

Comment: @JavaLatte so you believe that these are always are interchangeable and even the nuance in formality level is not too much?

Comment: that is not what I said.

Comment: @JavaLatte so please help me to know how and when I have to use each one of them; this was why I posted this question here. :)

Comment: I just heard "Thank you for being here" on TV. I guess we have at the minimum a hundred ways to say something on such an occasion.

Answer (score 2):

Like @JavaLatte said, they all sound natural but have slightly different levels of formality.

In general, "It is..." statements sound more formal, while "I..." statements sound more personal. In addition, contractions are less formal.

So from approximately most to least formal, I'd say:

> It is a pleasure to have you here.

Most formal - this would be appropriate to introduce a guest speaker at a conference, for example, or meeting a professional acquaintance.

> I am pleased to have you here.

This is a personal statement, so it is less formal than the above, but still more formal than the statements below using contractions. This would be appropriate if you were involved with having the person there, but would sound a bit stilted if you had a personal relationship with them.

> It’s nice to have you here.
>   It’s so good to have you here.

These are basically the same thing. "So good" is a stronger sentiment than "nice", so you can choose depending on how happy you actually are that the person is there :)

> I’m glad to have you here.

The least formal and most personal. This would be appropriate for a close friend or a colleague you are on friendly terms with, but may be a bit too friendly for, say, the visiting CEO.